# Making a bootable USB for Solaris

Tags: linux, installation, solaris, bootable-media

Is it possible to create a bootable USB of Oracle Solaris 11? I don't want to install Solaris on an Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris 11 is already available as a bootable live USB image.

Have a look to "USB Install Images for x86" in its [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html) page

Comment: I want to install Oracle Solaris with Windows 7..Is it possible ?

Comment: Please accept my reply if it answers your original question. Even slightly related, the one you just asked is different so should be asked as a new question. Thanks.

Comment: user1535580, see this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/472299/how-to-install-oracle-solaris-11-with-windows-7) for dual booting Oracle Solaris and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found this site maybe useful for you.
[DigitalBadger](http://www.markround.com/archives/65-Solaris-11-Review.html)
and
[Installing Solaris from a USB Disk](https://blogs.oracle.com/timc/entry/installing_solaris_from_a_usb)

Comment: This link is for Solaris 10. Solaris 11 way is simpler as the image is already distributed.