# How to install Oracle Solaris 11 with Windows 7?

Tags: multi-boot, bootloader, solaris

I want to install Oracle Solaris with Windows 7 without Virtual Machine...like means there should be an option of dual boot means that i can select the operating system during booting and can work in that Operating System.

Comment: You would need to see if Solaris even suports doing this.  It would have to install an alternative boot loader for this to work.  Of course you would also have to split the hdd into a parition Solaris actually supports.  All of this if its possible would be located in support articles on Oracle's website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is doable as long as you install Windows 7 first after provisioning a free partition for Solaris to install.

Solaris installer detects the Windows installation and add a GRUB entry to chainload Windows boot loader.

The [installation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/mediapart.html#scrolltoc) states:

> Oracle Solaris recognizes Windows and ensures that Windows partitions
>   remain unchanged during an installation. When the installation
>   completes, and the system reboots, the GRUB menu displays both the
>   Windows and the Oracle Solaris boot entries.

Of course, make sure you have a backup of any file of value before attempting the process as a mistake or unexpected event might brick your Windows installation.

That's the reason why using a virtualization technology like VirtualBox is recommended instead of risking wiping out your current partitions, which can easily happen if you aren't familiar with installing dual-boot OSes.

Comment: Well can you tell me the method and the software by which i can make the bootable Solaris in USB or on CD..??

Comment: The installation process is documented here; http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/mediapart.html#scrolltoc

Comment: Thanku Brother...I have installed the Oracle Solaris 11 ... Thanks Alot 4 Help